# What is a correct way to determine if clicked component has routerLink attribute?

Tags: javascript, angular, routerlink

I got a case, where I need to intercept click event and pick some additional config object from component it has **routerLink** attribute. How to determine if component has any? There is `elementRef.nativeElement.attributes.ng-reflect-router-link` but I believe, there is a better way to achieve that. Or, how to determine which selector was used to match element in my click-handler Directive - that would answer my question as well.

Comment: You can try to inject the routerlink into the constructor of the component.

Comment: I'd need to do this in literally every clickable component. No way :(

Answer (score 2):

You can add a click event to your links which have a `routerLink` attribute. Take a look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36214759/8843654

Your links would look something like this: `<a  [routeLink]=['User'] (click)="myCallback()">User</a>`

Comment: That's a solution but I'd like to avoid adding that everywhere in my application. Click-handler directive which matches elements through [href], [routerLink] does almost all out of the box...